# install sql file through joomla component

Tags: php, joomla, joomla1.5

recently we have made a custom component for our client. Now we built the install file for this component, through the following xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<install type="component" version="1.5.0">  
<name>customblog</name>  
<author>Jogesh Sharma</author>  
<creationDate>March 2013</creationDate>  
<copyright>Copyright (C) 2013 Open Source Matters. All rights reserved.</copyright>  
<license>http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html GNU/GPL</license>  
<authorEmail>hello@webomnizz.com</authorEmail>  
<authorUrl>http://webomnizz.com</authorUrl>  
<version>1.5.0</version>  
<description>This component manage all the Blog sections!</description>  
<installfile>install.customblog.php</installfile>  
<uninstallfile>uninstall.customblog.php</uninstallfile>  

<files>      
    <filename>customblog.php</filename>      
    <filename>customblog.html.php</filename>
</files>
<files folder="images">
    <filename>style.css</filename>
    <filename>plus-icon.png</filename>
    <filename>twitter-icon.png</filename>
    <filename>facebook-icon.png</filename>
</files>      

<install>      
    <sql>          
        <file driver="mysql">install.mysql.sql</file>      
    </sql>  
</install>    

<uninstall>      
    <sql>          
        <file driver="mysql">uninstall.mysql.sql</file>      
    </sql>  
</uninstall>      

<administration>      
    <menu img="js/ThemeOffice/component.png">Blog Component</menu>      
    <submenu>          
        <menu link="option=com_customblog">Blog</menu>
        <menu link="option=com_customblog&amp;c=general">General Options</menu>
    </submenu>            
    <files>          
        <filename>install.mysql.sql</filename>          
        <filename>uninstall.mysql.sql</filename>          
        <filename>admin.customblog.php</filename>          
        <filename>admin.customblog.html.php</filename>          
        <filename>toolbar.customblog.php</filename>          
        <filename>toolbar.customblog.html.php</filename>          
        <filename>index.html</filename>
    </files>
    <files folder="tables">
        <filename>customblog.php</filename> 
        <filename>general.php</filename>
    </files>  
</administration>
</install>
```

but the problem is our sql file `install.mysql.sql` is not installed in joomla, i don't know why, and during installation it's not provide any error message etc. I am using joomla 1.5.26,

Can anyone tell me what i missed??

**Update:** here is my `install.mysql.sql` file:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `#__blog` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `full_text` mediumtext NOT NULL,
 `state` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
 `publish_up` date NOT NULL,
 `gp_button` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 `fb_button` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 `tw_button` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 `user_id` tinyint(2) NOT NULL,
 `social_key` tinyint(2) DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);


CREATE TABLE `#__generalopt` (
  `id` int(2) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `title` varchar(200) default NULL,
  `gp_status` tinyint(2) default NULL,
  `fb_status` tinyint(2) default NULL,
  `tw_status` tinyint(2) default NULL,
  `userImg` varchar(200) default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
);
INSERT INTO `jos_generalopt` VALUES(1, 'General Options', 1, 1, 1, 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/12/User_icon_2.svg/120px-User_icon_2.svg.png');
```

**Structure**:
[image]

Comment: Just asking stupid, but your server does run mysql and not a different database engine?

Comment: why are you developing a component for Joomla 1.5. You should be developing for Joomla 2.5 or 3.0. You're not even using MVC standards :/

Comment: @Lodder because of our client's requirement, yes i didn't followed the `MVC` standard because this is my first component in joomla..

Comment: your client demanded you use 1.5? I hope you told him/her why it's not a good idea. If this is your first component then I would honestly recommend sticking to MVC standards. much easier in the long run

Answer (score 0):

You must put `install.mysql.sql` in `admin` folder, even though it's not mentioned in the path. Leave xml as it is, just create a new folder `admin` and move `install.mysql.sql` there, then Joomla will be able to find it

Comment: i get this error after creating folder `admin` and moved the `install.mysql.sql` file into `admin/install.mysql.sql` but not changed the **xml file** : JInstaller::install: File 'D:\wamp\www\joomla_1.5._new\tmp\install_515a90530e0f7\com_customblog\install.mysql.sql' does not exist.

Comment: sorry, you need to edit `<filename>install.mysql.sql</filename>`, I missed that line, add path `<filename>admin/install.mysql.sql</filename>`

Comment: i did like `<files folder="admin">   <filename>install.mysql.sql</filename>          
   <filename>uninstall.mysql.sql</filename>
  </files>` this, this can't provide error, but not installing the database..

Comment: seems fine now... if you enter sql directly using phpmyadmin or something, is everything ok? just to make sure there is no problem with sql...

Comment: last idea: make it as `<file driver="mysql" charset="utf8">` and save as **utf8 no BOM**

Comment: thanks but i have did another trick, to install my database and it works perfect, http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?p=1389007